# Which object will be used when I have bean definition in config file as well as using @Autowire annotation

Tags: java, spring

I am looking at some existing application code and I am confuse because of the code over there, here is the scenario:

In the class `ABC`, I have autowiring as:

```
@Autowired
RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

Then in my spring bean config file, I bean definition as:

```
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate"/>
```

In the class `ABC` I am using rest template as:

```
restTemplate.postForObject(url, requestObject, String.class);
```

My questions are:

- when I am using the rest template then the object which I am using is the one which is because of autowiring or the one which is defined in bean config file?
- In case of autowiring since I have not specified the scope, so it will be singleton, right?

---

As per comments and answers, below is minimalistic reproducible code which shows that even when I have auto-wiring and bean definition in bean config file, I can run the program and there are no issues.

Main class:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SpringTest {

    @Autowired
    Person person;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        generalTest();
    }

    private static void generalTest() {
        testApplicationContext();
    }

    private static void testApplicationContext() {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("bean.xml");

        SpringTest springTest = (SpringTest) applicationContext.getBean("springTest");

        if(springTest.person == null){
            System.out.println("person is NULL");
        } else{
            System.out.println("person is not NULL");
        }

    }

}
```

Bean file:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.learn.stackoverflow.general"/>
    <!-- as such below is useless because The use of <context:component-scan> implicitly enables the functionality of <context:annotation-config>. 
    There is usually no need to include the <context:annotation-config> element when using <context:component-scan>. -->
    <context:annotation-config /> 

   <bean id = "person" class = "com.learn.stackoverflow.general.Person" scope="singleton">
   </bean>

</beans>
```

Person class:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Scope(value="singleton")
public class Person implements InitializingBean, Human {
    @Autowired
    SpringTest springTest;

    static{
        System.out.println("Static initialization from Person");
    }

    {
        System.out.println("Instance initialization  from Person");
    }

    public Person(){
        System.out.println("Constructor  from Person");
    }

    public void sayHello(){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("InitializingBean.afterPropertiesSet  from Person");
    }

    @Override
    public void breathe() {
        System.out.println("person is breathing...");
    }

}
```

Output is `person is not NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When IoC container finds a bean definition defined in the bean config file then same definition is used for injecting the instance, and if IoC container doesn't find one then it creates an instance and injects the same.

Below is a little tweaked example which demonstrates above concept, you can play around with it my commenting and uncommenting the bean definition mentioned in bean config file. **Please read carefully my code comments.**

**SpringTest:**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SpringTest {
    @Autowired
    Person person;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        generalTest();
    }

    private static void generalTest() {
        testApplicationContext();
    }

    private static void testApplicationContext() {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("C:\\E_Drive\\Projects\\Workspace\\Test\\CS101\\src\\com\\learn\\stackoverflow\\general\\bean.xml");
        SpringTest springTest = (SpringTest) applicationContext.getBean("springTest");

        if(springTest.person == null){
            System.out.println("person is NULL");
        } else{
            System.out.println("person is not NULL");
            springTest.person.sayHello(); // here output will be “Hello, ppj” if you keep the config file bean definition and when you remove that bean definition then output is “Hello, null”
        }

    }
}
```

**Bean config:**

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.learn.stackoverflow.general"/>

    <!-- once you get comment out below, IoC will instatiate a bean and will inject the same in SpringTest's autowiring of Person class  -->
   <!-- <bean id = "person" class = "com.learn.stackoverflow.general.Person" scope="singleton">
      <constructor-arg name="name" value="ppj"></constructor-arg>
   </bean> -->

</beans>
```

**Person:**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Scope(value="singleton")
public class Person {
    private String name;

    @Autowired
    SpringTest springTest;

    public Person(){
        System.out.println("Constructor from Person");
    }

    public Person(String name){
        System.out.println("String Constructor from Person");
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void sayHello(){
        System.out.println("Hello, " + name);
    }

}
```

Comment: "if IoC container doesn't find one then it creates an instance". This isn't correct, Spring will not create bean definition out of thin air for you (unless you are using Spring Boot and even then it create only specific beans according to it's autoconfiguration), here you have a bean definition of Person because it was created by the @Component annotation and the component-scan.

Comment: @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope This is very much obvious, intention was not to tell the step-by-step process on how Spring will create the instance but to explain what OP was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The config file tells Spring to **create** a bean with an id of "restTemplate" which is of type org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate. The default scope is a single instance of the bean.

Then in the code, since there exists a bean of **type** RestTemplate, the bean (which happens to have an id of "restTemplate" is auto wired.

"restTemplate" as an id or a class attribute that also has "restTemplate" as its name is not important.  The bean can be injected since it's of same type.  (And also beceause there's only 1 of that type.)

Comment: even if I remove the XML bean definition still I have the object because of autowiring

Comment: You did a full clean/build and still able to run the app?  It shouldn't even start.

Comment: @pjj autowiring means that Spring will **set** the value for you. To set it, the Spring Context should have created a bean of that type. Probable what somebody did was to redefine the bean maybe to use custom properties for it, but the bean has a default value and factory to create it.

Comment: @AndrewS Ok. Please correct me on my understanding - since my spring bean config file has `restTemplate` so that instance is injected to my autowired `Person person;`. And when I remove that bean definition from my spring bean config file then Spring's IoC container will  create an instance of `RestTemplate` and will inject the same?

Answer (score 1):

`@Autowired` doesn't create bean, it will take the existing bean declaration that match with the expected type and put it in the field. In the XML you have your bean declaration, without it your bean won't exist (unless you are using Spring Boot, in which case it might get automatically created if it doesn't exists).

You can use now `@Inject` instead of `@Autowired` since JSR-299 and if you have a recent version of Spring and javax.inject dependencies. Both do exactly the same thing but @Inject is clearer.

Comment: I don't think that's true, because even if I remove the XML bean definition still I have the object because of autowiring.

Comment: @pjj if it works when you comment the element in XML then it's being created by another factory, but Spring has a bean of that type. Otherwise, you would get an exception when executing the application.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I tested this though a standalone Java program, and I have a bean definition in XML file as well as autowire and program runs and I see that I have object.

Comment: @pjj are you using Spring Boot or Spring only?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I think Spring only. I created a standalone Java program and included the Spring JARs in classpath while running.

Comment: @pjj please update your question and provide your pom.xml. There's no such thing as *magic* in the programming world.

Comment: @pjj I can see the code and there's nothing wrong with it. You define your `SpringTest` bean decorating it with `@Component` annotation and then in XML file you state `<context:component-scan base-package="com.learn.stackoverflow.general"/>`. That's not magic, that's Spring 101.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I never said it is magic. I want to understand what's going on, can you please explain me.

Comment: @pjj that's explained in tutorials. SO is not meant to write tutorials for people. Please explain what's your specific question.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I have already mentioned my question in my post, on what I am trying to understand.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza BTW, very humbly, everything is written in tutorials but people post questions to get the help to understand when they can't understand in tutorials, if what you think is true then there should be no questions on SO.

Comment: @pjj your original question was about why `RestTemplate` instance was injected. I requested your pom.xml to see what may happen and you post something entirely different that is about Spring managing the beans you define. You don't focus on your original question and instead ask to understand how Spring works. This is not how the site works. If your original question would be "I need to understand how `@Autowired` works" or similar, then I would have answered something different.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I think you didn't understand my question, my question was "*when I am using the rest template then the object which I am using is the one which is because of autowiring or the one which is defined in bean config file?*" ...

Comment: @pjj and these answers and me are stating that `@Autowired` won't create an instance of the bean, instead Spring will inject an instance of that bean in that field. When asking for code example to haver better understanding of this case, you provide something entirely different...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I am not having any pom.xml so how can I provide you. Based on your comment, I provided you a minimalist reproducible code example, I don't know what else you were expecting.

Comment: @pjj I'm requesting a minimal example where you inject `RestTemplate`, you have `RestTemplate` bean defined in XML, a list of the libraries you use and whatever else you have so we can reproduce the problem in our machines.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I have emulated the same behavior using standalone Java program and POJOs, is it not ok? If you specifically need example with `RestTemplate` then sorry I will not be able to provide that, it will take time to create such an example, so I quickly emulated the whole behaviour in standalone Java program.

Comment: @pjj it is not ok because you state that if you comment the bean definition then your program still runs. So, `RestTemplate` bean should be defined somewhere else to make it work, while your example is easier to understand why it works and how to make it work. Sorry for you because then we cannot help you.